# Fullcalendar jquery with custom date range in timeline view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I need to implement custom date range in fullcalendar scheduler but didn't find any related help. My requirement is to have custom timelineview with user defined start and end date so calendar displays only days which are selected by user.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What about this? http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/

Comment: how can you add custom date range selected by user itself. Like Selecting Start Date (01/01/2015) and End Date (01/03/2015). Hope you understand my question :).

Comment: You read the data given by the user and provide them to your custom view (check the documentation link I gave).
For example, if you inherit your custom view from the AgendaView, line 43, you can set a date range: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/src/agenda/AgendaView.js
Now you connect the dots, I won't code it for you ;)

Comment: We need to know more about your code to help